# What is the preferred way to configure a Spring Boot Test application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration

I have configured my application using `@Configuration` annotated classes in the `config` package:

```
main
    java
        com.ourcompany
            config
                PersistenceConfig
                JacksonConfig
            persistence
            ...
            Application
test
    java
        com.ourcompany
            persistence
                PersistenceTest
```

The configuration gets picked up by the `Application` class without a problem:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        SpringApplication.run( Application.class, args );
    }

}
```

However, the Test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataMongoTest
public class PersistenceTest {
    ...
}
```

does not pick up the configuration, unless I specify the name of the configuration class in the annotation:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = PersistenceConfig.class)
```

I find this quite unintuitive, since I have to explicitly list all my `config` classes.

What is the idiomatic way to share the configuration in Spring Boot?

**EDIT**

In the end the problem was with including both `@DataMongoTest` and `@SpringBootTest` at the same time. Removing the `@DataMongoTest` and annotating the test class as:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
public class PersistenceTest {
    ...
}
```

Solved the problem. However, the question as to what is the **best practice** remains.

Comment: You can just use @SpringBootTest(classes=Application.class), this will load all the classes and application context,  
or  
Define another class with lots of @Import(.....class, ...class) and use that in @SpringBootTest

Comment: Thank you! I tried `@SpringBootTest(classes=Application.class)` and it does not work. Do you have any ideas what might be the problem?

Comment: Your main springboot application class is called Application right?

Comment: @pvpkiran, yes exactly. I also tried to use `@SpringBootConfiguration` instead of `@Configuration` for the `PersistenceConfig` and `JacksonConfig` classes, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: try with this annotations 
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes =Application.class)

Comment: It wills start scanning from the package the test (without specifying the application class) is defined in also `@SpringBootTest` and `@DataMongoTest` are more or less mutually exclusive.

Comment: @pvpkiran Unfortunately that does not work.

Comment: @M.Deinum I removed the `@SpringBootTest` but I still cannot get the test to pick up the configuration from the `config` package. What would be the most Spring-Bootish way to solve this problem?